# Is it possible to make comments in dtx file?

Tags: dtx

When writing `dtx` file, is it possible to make comments in the section behind the `%</driver>` line?
In more detail, I mean the commented lines, which don't appear in the generated files. Some hidden code for developers or author's notes... Maybe not very useful as it inflated the source code, but interesting to know.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not very clear, but depending on what you mean you can make comments like

```
% this
```

or like

```
^^A this
```

The `^^A` form for use in documentation sections where `%` is ignored.

Comment: I'm preparing _dtx_ file, sometimes I want make (ToDo) note in the process of writing. But this comment is not intended to be published. Is it possible to make user comments?

Comment: yes sure: `%^^A this is a comment`